# How to have ConEmu execute a powershell script at startup?

Tags: powershell, conemu

I use the following command to launch new ConEmu powershell consoles.

```
ConEmu64.exe /config "shell" /dir "c:\" /cmd powershell -new_console:n
```

I would like to pass an additional argument to specify a powershell script to run at startup of a new console. The following almost works but only prints the whole command and does not actually execute it:

```
ConEmu64.exe /config "shell" /dir "c:\" /cmd 'powershell -noexit -Command {Write-host "Hello world"}' -new_console:n
```

which produces:

```
Write-host Hello world
C:\>
```

while I am expecting:

```
Hello world
C:\>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove single quotas around your command. ConEmu executes intact string (command) which follows `/cmd` switch, with only exception - all `-new_console...` and `-cur_console...` are removed from this string before starting console.

```
ConEmu64.exe /config "shell" /dir "c:\" /cmd powershell -noexit -Command Write-host "Hello world" -new_console:n
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Figured it out, its a quoting issue, but there is still some weirdness going on:

```
/config "shell" /dir "c:\" /cmd 'powershell -noexit -Command "& Write-host `"Hello world""' -new_console:n
```

That works and produces the expected:

```
Hello World
C:\>
```

but if you look carefully the quote at the end of "Hello World" is not escaped while the first one is. If I use the seemingly correct syntax:

```
/config "shell" /dir "c:\" /cmd 'powershell -noexit -Command "& Write-host `"Hello world`""' -new_console:n
```

I get

```
Hello world`
C:\>
```